# Ошибка запуска Apache в Windows 8.1

Tags: apache, apache2, localhost

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить ошибку.
При запуске через файл start-server.bat выдает ошибку:
Специфическая ошибка службы: 1
Для вызова дополнительной справки наберите NET HELPMSG 3547.

В логах Windows ошибка следующего содержания:
The Apache service named  reported the following error:

> > > AH00014: Configuration check failed     .

Спасибо!

[image: NET HELPMSG 3547]

Comment: Правь конфиг апача. Запусти `httpd.exe -t` она тебе ошибку покажет. Её исправляешь и пробуешь заново.

Comment: Выдает ошибку: 
AH00014: Configuration check failed

Собственно это и суть проблемы
Буду признателен в помощи)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка переводится как "не прошла проверка конфигурации". Лечится командой [`apachectl configtest`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apachectl.html) и фактическими действиями по исправлению недостатков конфигурации. Команда найдена на [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/232145/command-to-check-validity-of-apache-server-config-files).